# Should singulars or plurals be used in lists of quantity after a number that is plural when the list is "[number]x item"?

Tags: lists

Should singulars or plurals be used in lists of quantity after a number that is plural when the list is "[number]x item"?

For example, in the following list, should entry 2 be "6x apples" or "6x apple?"

1. 1x banana
2. 6x apple(s?)

I think that "6x apples" is better but I'm not sure and cannot find any other references for this very specific scenario elsewhere.

Comment: If you want 6 apples, then *6x apple*. (6 x 1 apple = 6 apples)

Comment: This is not about English usage. Such a list is a merely a structure in which placeholders hold numbers and the names of related items. There is no need to be grammatical.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Given that the singular is only used with the number 1 (or -1 if appropriate) I would suggest that the plural is more appropriate for a fixed list even if you are using the multiplication symbol. I'd rather see "Apples ×6, Oranges ×0, Bananas ×1" than the same list with singulars.

Comment: @BoldBen I agree, but _lists are off-topic_. Seriously, it is essentially a jargon. Why $3 and 6cm rather than 3 $s / 3 Ds and 6 cms?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _lists are off topic_ That's good enough for me, no more need be said!

Comment: Do I need scare-quotes as well as italics?

Comment: Only if you're writing on Halloween :-)